# php - if statement, with two factors

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a private messaging script, where users can send messages to each other.

I have a problem showing if the user viewed the message.

What I am trying to do is that if:

- User1 sent the PM to User2

  - The PM should be marked viewed for user1, but not user2.
- User2 replies to the PM to User1

  - The PM should be marked viewed for user2, but not user 1.

In my database I have:
`viewed_sender` and `viewed_receiver`. They are either 0 or 1 (1 if the message has been viewed, and 0 if it hasn't)

`viewed_sender` standard value is of course 1.

When writing a reply post, I update `viewed_sender` and `viewed_receiver` like this:

```
    if($pmData['sender_id'] == $userdata['id']): //If you're the sender
        $sender = 1;
    else:
        $sender = 0;
    endif;

    //Update viewed $id is the id of the conversation.
    if($sender == 0){
        mysql_query("UPDATE private_messages SET viewed_receiver='0' WHERE id='$id'");
        if(mysql_affected_rows()==0)
            return 2;
    }
```

Then when I am showing whether the message is viewed for the logged in user, I do it like this:

```
        //Viewed.

        if($convoData['sender_id'] == $userdata['id']):
            $sender = 1;
        else:
            $sender = 0;
        endif;       

        if($sender == 1 && $convoData['viewed_sender'] == 1){
            $viewed = false;
        }elseif($sender == 0 && $convoData['viewed_receiver'] == 0){
            $viewed = true;
        }else{
            $viewed = false;
        }   

if($viewed == true){ 
echo '<img src="/images/icons/comments.png" style="border-radius: 0px !important;-moz-border-radius:0px !important;-webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;float: right;margin-right: 30px;" height="12" width="12">';              
}
```

That doesn't work. What am I doing wrong in the if statement?

Comment: Why bothering with marking it viewed for the sender? He WROTE it, no need to save that he saw it.

Comment: Well, if he receives a reply from the receiver of the message, then it should be marked viewed for him

Comment: Can you elaborate on "That doesn't work"? By the way, it's not clear to me why you set `$viewed = false` when the user is the sender and `viewed_sender` is true.